# Dominating set approximation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

Is the following a $\ln n$ approximation algorithm to the dominating set problem? I was thinking of the following algorithm:
Given a graph G(V,E), find a spanning tree of $G$, pick only non-leaf nodes. I'm not sure how to bound the number of non-leaf nodes, however.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific way of constructing the spanning tree, you can't give much guarantee on the number of leaves.

For instance, take the complete graph $K_n$.

There is a spanning tree that consists of a path of length $n$.  It has $2$ leaves and $n - 2$ non-leaves.
Your algorithm would give $n - 2$, whereas the smallest dominating set has size $1$.

Maybe $K_n$ is a bit of an extreme counter-example, any Hamiltonian graph will have a path as a spanning tree, and the same problem occurs.